# deployer composer exception - how to debug?

Tags: laravel, deployment, php-deployer

I am using deployer to deploy my laravel application to an LEMP stack. The setup has successfully copied all the files to the server in the release folder, however the composer install always fails, with the error code of

```
  ... Extracting archivePackage aferrandini/phpqrcode is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use endroid/qr-code instead.                                                                                         
  Generating optimized autoload files                                                                                                                                                                            
  > post-autoload-dump: Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump                                                                                                                                  
  > post-autoload-dump: @php artisan package:discover                                                                                                                                                            
  Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I have tried running composer install on the server manually as the deployer user and this works with out any issues.

The error generated does not give me much clue as to why its failing so I wonder if someone could point me in the right direction of how to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the error command on the server and it gave me more informaiton I needed to work out the issue package. It turned out to be the phpstorm ide helper which is included for composer dev only.

```
php artisan package:discover
```